# Android alpha transparency for background sprite for fade in effect is not working as expected

Tags: android, andengine

I am using AndEngine-GLES2 and when i am trying to fade in the background for a new scene, the image is first displayed for a fraction of second and then it fades in as i needed.  But that image being displayed without alpha transparency initially for a fraction of a second is making it look glitchy.

Here is my code to load the image

I am loading the sprite like,

`bgSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, bgTextureRegion, LaunchGame.getSharedInstance().getEngine().getVertexBufferObjectManager());`

And I am setting alpha transparency and fade in effects as

```
bgSprite.setBlendFunction(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    final IEntityModifier iem = new AlphaModifier(1,0.0f,1.0f);
    iem.setAutoUnregisterWhenFinished(true);
    bgSprite.registerEntityModifier(iem);
    attachChild(bgSprite);
```

I tried to override the preDraw function of sprite but it dint help.  What could be the problem or any more data required? Or am I missing something stupid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add:

```
bgSprite.setAlpha(0.0f);
```

before you attach your background.
By default your sprite is attached with alpha (1.0) (thats why it shows up for a sec, and then the modifier is fired so instantly it goes to alpha(0.0f) and goes to 1.0f again slowly.

Comment: Yup.  It is as simple as you said.